# How to copy only selected file types in WinSCP?

Tags: ftp, winscp

I want to download only php, html, css, xml and js files from FTP server. How to do this with WinSCP (4.2.4)?

Comment: In general, for this goal, it can be useful [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) too. (Note it exists a version for windows too). Read the options to include only specified file pattern (`*.css`...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a simple app specific question like this belongs on the app's support forum, or perhaps SuperUser but not ServerFault, but as I know and I'm taking a work break I'll answer anyway)

You would have to use the Select Files command from the Mark menu (usually bound to the key numpad:+) and type your match pattern (i.e. `*.php;*.js`) into there. You can then operate on the selected files as usual.

Comment: How to select files in subfolders too? "Including directories" option doesn't work.

Comment: That is probably not possible. You would need a client that you could script. Or perhaps use another protocol if possible (for instance using rsync over the SSH connection if permitted by your server config - a combination of its --recursive option and --include/--exclude options woudl do what you are looking for).

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @David Spillett is correct for files in the current directory.

If you want to do this recursively, use a [transfer file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom).

The mask would be the same as David suggested, i.e. `*.php;*.js`.

For more details, check [file mask syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).